# Oddly NumberFormatException in android

Tags: java, android

It's seems like integer but it not parse with Integer.parse() How can I fix it ?

```
 int a= Integer.parseInt(lhs.getViewCount());
```

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "6125635424"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
        at com.youtubetracker.adapters.MyChannelListAdapter$1.compare(MyChannelListAdapter.java:46)
        at com.youtubetracker.adapters.MyChannelListAdapter$1.compare(MyChannelListAdapter.java:37)
```

Comment: its not integer it range is more than integer capacity. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) over long and float.

```
BigInteger value= new BigInteger(lhs.getViewCount());
```

You can convert that value to `int` , `long` or `float`.

Form Java Doc [intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue())

> Converts this BigInteger to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum Range of Integer is 2147483647 and you are converting 6125635424 to integer. This is the main reason behind the Exception.

`Long.parseLong(lhs.getViewCount());`

Will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Replace: `int a= Integer.parseInt(lhs.getViewCount());`

With

```
 Long a= Long.parseInt(String.valueOf(lhs.getViewCount()));
```

Answer (score 1):

'6125635424' cannot store in Integer you need to store in Double or Long.

Try this

```
Long a = Long.parseLong(lhs.getViewCount().toString());
```